# Ajax-returned elements do not trigger in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

In the HTML, a dropdown with the ID="project_pick" will fire a change event, sending the selected value to the getallreports.php file. This works. The PHP file does a MySQL lookup and returns values inside some HTML. This also works, and looks great on the page. Here below is the jQuery/ajax code that sends the selected item to the PHP file:

```
$('#project_pick').change(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getallreports.php",
        data: "project_id=" + $(this).val(),
        success:function(data){
            $('#reportstable').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

The returned data appears inside the specified div, and includes anchor tags with specific IDs that should allow other JQuery events to happen. Snippet of returned HTML:

```
<table><tr>
    <td>Report 1</td><td><a href="#" id="change_1">click to change</a></td>
    <td>Report 2</td><td><a href="#" id="change_2">click to change</a></td>
</tr></table>
```

The jQuery code to trigger on the above click event is:

```
$('#change_1').click(function() {
    alert('Change Report One was clicked');
});
```

However, clicking the above anchor tag does nothing. Also, the returned HTML does not even appear in the source -- although it shows on the screen and in firebug.

What am I missing? How can I get that click event to fire?

EDIT:

I've been reminded about the .on('click', etc) event (thanks Michael and Zirkms), but when I attempted to add it to my code the dropdown's .change event stopped firing. Perhaps the below code needs a facelift?

```
$('#project_pick').on(change(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getallreports.php",
        data: "project_id=" + $(this).val(),
        success:function(data){
            $('#reportstable').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Dynamically created elements will never show in the page source, since that source is the static markup downloaded by the original http request.  They will, and do, show in Firebug or other DOM inspection tools.

Comment: It isn't clear from your question. Did you define the `$('#test').click()` _before_ it was created in the DOM? If so, it won't be bound. You need to use [`.on('click')`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind future elements.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for that explanation. I had seen some stuff about .on(), but when I added it the dropdown stopped working. Clearly I did it wrong. I'll edit the OP to post code sample. Note that the returned HTML should have several such clickable IDs (I am returning a list of reports and corresponding "click to change" anchor tags. When one is clicked, user can choose a different report document. Therefore, each must have its own ID.)

Comment: @FUTURE READERS - For those who wonder about the #test ref in Michael and zirkms' responses, the orig question showed a table returned with a single clickable anchor tag with ID="test". I re-edited the question to show two clickable anchor tags, because I thought that was important, and I did a better job of describing how they would be used. I also renamed the <a> tag IDs to "change_1" and "change_2" from "test". What I didn't understand from M's and Z's answers was that .on('click', #element...) is implemented at these change_1 and change_2 tags, NOT at the #project_pick dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the moment of `$('#test').click()` code execution `#test` didn't exist in the DOM, so you didn't bind that handler to somewhere.

Use

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function() { ... });
```

instead

Or (**better**) if you have a particular node where you insert the retrieved html - use some particular selector rather than `$(document)` like

```
$('#reportstable').on(...)
```

> does not even appear in the source

In the "view source" browsers usually show the response from the server as it was retrieved on request, without reflecting JS DOM modifications.

Comment: Thanks zerkms. I'm not clear, though, how to specify $('#reportstable').on(...) if the jQuery trigger is through the #project_pick dropdown element? How would you modify my code above?

Comment: @gibberish: I cannot understand your current issue.

Comment: Actually, I did not correctly understand your answer. I misunderstood and thought the .on() should apply to the #project_pick dropdown, when you intended it to apply to each "click to change" element. All fixed. Thank you.